# How to get socket's buffered data when socket closed due to network loss?

Tags: java, tcp

I want to know is there any option to read previously written data to socket when socket get closed due to network loss ?

Although my application is in Java environment, but I want to know answer for general purpose OS behavior. If anyone know in terms of winsocks and unix socket behavior they also welcome.

Comment: Seeing how there are many different types of socket implementations and many different ways for the network to become unstable/shutdown which determines whether the data has actually left the local network or not, this question is pretty broad. If you could, try making it a bit more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket doesn't get closed due to network loss. Only you can close your socket.

The *connection* can be *reset* due to network problems.

In this case all pending data is discarded. Nothing you can do about it.